# Send email from gmail account to an outlook account with python?

Tags: python

I'm working on a transfer project and want to polish it up by enabling the user to send a receipt to their email address from inside the tkinter GUI. I've managed to send emails to another gmail account but if I try to send to an outlook account nothing happens, no errors popup in IDLE and the code keeps running smoothly (weird). Below is the code I'm using right now and am simply wondering how I could modify it to make outlook sending work.

```
    import smtplib
    content = 'example'
    mail = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
    mail.ehlo()
    mail.starttls()
    mail.login('notmyactualemail@gmail.com','notmyactualpassword')
    mail.sendmail('notmyactualemail@gmail.com','emailiwanttosendto',content)
    mail.close()
```

Comment: Is it going to the spam mailbox in Outlook?

Comment: Had to do a little bit of digging, turns out you're right and it gets sent to junk mail. Problem is the college I'm with deletes junk mail instantly so I had to test with a separate account...I might have a problem.

Comment: You might be interested in using a mailing service like [Mandrill](https://www.mandrill.com/) instead of using SMTP directly.

Comment: Is Mandrill free? (Would seem a little wasteful if I'm only going to use the service for a college project)